# XML Parsing using XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, zimbra

In My application, I'm getting an `XML Response` and I'm trying to convert that XML Response using `XmlNode`.

My XML File : [File](http://omgroup.uandmeplus.com/invitefiles/xmlresponse.txt)

The XML Content will be like :

```
<account name="santosh@mx.omit-solutions.com" id="876e6b55-5a9c-44ff-a418-af737c47d2af">
  <a n="mobile">91 998977245009</a>
  <a n="zimbraMailDeliveryAddress">santosh@mx.omit-solutions.com</a>
  <a n="zimbraPrefIMLogChats">TRUE</a>
</account>
<account name="mani@mx.omit-solutions.com" id="ce91d3bf-83b8-4a55-a92e-2e080fa4a21b">
  <a n="zimbraMailDeliveryAddress">mani@mx.omit-solutions.com</a>
  <a n="zimbraPrefShowSearchString">FALSE</a>
  <a n="zimbraPrefIMLogChats">TRUE</a>
</account>
```

Here I'm showing two sample accounts from that XML Response and I need to loop through all the `account nodes` and get the `zimbraMailDeliveryAddress` which will be surely available in every node and also `mobile` element value `('91 998977245009')` which may not be available in every node(i.e. the  tag wont be available at all).

Is there a way to get these values?

I've tried using the `XmlNamespaceManager` like this :

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("bc", "urn:zimbraAdmin");
XmlNode result = doc.SelectSingleNode("//bc:account", mgr);
if (result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0}.", result.InnerText);
}
else
{
    // handle case that no element was found
    Console.WriteLine("No element found.");
}
```

But by using this code, I'm getting only `first account node` data and I'm unable to loop through `all account nodes`.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Maybe `SelectNodes` instead `SelectSingleNode` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest ditching `XmlDocument` and XPath and using LINQ to XML instead:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = "urn:zimbraAdmin";

foreach (var account in doc.Descendants(ns + "account"))
{
    var mobile = (string)account.Elements(ns + "a")
        .SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("n") == "mobile");

    var address = (string)account.Elements(ns + "a")
        .SingleOrDefault(e => (string)e.Attribute("n") == "zimbraMailDeliveryAddress");
}
```

See a working demo using your file here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UOV40v

Answer (score 0):

SelectSingleNode will only return a single node. SelectNodes returns a list of nodes (XmlNodeList) and may be what you are looking for to get them all.

[Link to the specification of XmlNode.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)